# How to update a child component in Angular when a function returns a new value?

Tags: angular

Given are two components: **Parent** and **Child**.

**parent.ts**

```
class Parent {
    state = 0;
    ...
};
```

**parent.html**

```
<child [state]='state'> </child>
```

Whenever I update `state` in **Parent**, the update is reflected in the child component.

Due to a refactoring, I had to remove `state` from **Parent** and instead have now a singleton class:

```
class Application {
    private static getState();
    private static setState(state: number);
}
```

Whenever I call `Application.setState(0)`, the child will not be informed anymore. What is a common technique to let the child component know that `Application.getState()` will now return a different value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best to use Angular BehaviorSubject Service and get the components to subscribe to the change event. I have created a simple Pokemon Api that has exactly what you need. It is very easy to see what is happening in the source code.

The service is as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class PokemonFilterService {
  private pokemonfilterStatus = new PokemonFilter();
  private pokemonFilterSource = new BehaviorSubject<PokemonFilter>(this.pokemonfilterStatus);

  // this updates the data from the component
  change(data: PokemonFilter) : void {
    this.pokemonFilterSource.next(data);
  }

  // this lets the subscribing component know the data has changed
  public filterDataHasChanged(): Observable<PokemonFilter> {
    return this.pokemonFilterSource.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The pokemon-header page has this code

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-pokemon-header',
  templateUrl: './pokemon-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pokemon-header.component.scss']
})
export class PokemonHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  typeList: Array<PokeTypes>;
  pokemonFilter: PokemonFilter;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private pokemonFilterService: PokemonFilterService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // one api call - get the list once and pass it down
    // fyi the api call was cached by the resolver
    this.typeList = this.route.snapshot.data['typeList'].results as Array<PokeTypes>;
    this.typeList = this.typeList.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : -1);
    // use this service to check if the filter values changes from detail component (reset)
    this.pokemonFilterService.filterDataHasChanged().subscribe((pokemonFilter: PokemonFilter) => {
      if (pokemonFilter) {
        this.pokemonFilter = pokemonFilter;
      }
    });
  }

  filterChanged(): void {
    this.pokemonFilterService.change(this.pokemonFilter)
  }
}
```

the pokemon-detail can subscribe and change the data and the header component will be notified.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
this.pagingOffset = 0;
this.getPokemons(this.pagingOffset);

// use this service to check if the filter values change (reset)
    this.pokemonFilterService.filterDataHasChanged().subscribe((pokemonFilter : PokemonFilter) => {
      if (pokemonFilter) {
        this.pokemonFilter = pokemonFilter;
      }
    });
  }
```

**Summary**

In one component you change the data and in the other component, you subscribe to the data. The components can be unrelated.

See full source code here https://github.com/tfa7